# Is it possible to change signal handler return point?

Tags: c

My first post here, so sorry if something not according to the rules.
Need advice for a problem in C.

I'm using a signal handler(SIGALRM)  with timeout on an input from user (Stdin). 
If  the user didn't type anything then:

1. timeout expired
2. signal handler called
3. (PROBLEM) - > it returns to the same line before timeout occurred.

IMPORTANT :
I can't use select and can't use poll functions because it's a third party mechanism I use and must use their methods. 
They eventually use select, but it's not straightforward and I just need to use their method.

The problem is:
After returning from signal handler i"m still 'stuck' on the same line waiting for input. 
I can't use longjmp, can't call other method, can't print message to the user, can't use goto. 
All unsafe from handler and creating errors.

The code looks something like this:

```
sa.sigaction(SIGALRM, &handler,Null):
.
. 
While(done! =1)
{
   alarm(20); //20 seconds timeout started
   If(ReadLineMethod()>0)  //wait for successful input from stdin
   {
        If(inputErr ==1)
         {
          **here(for example)  I want to print user that timeout        occured and return from the program (exit) **
           } 
    alarm(0);
    done==1;
    // Do stuff here
    } 
}



/* Rest of the program before exit */
```

The while is for asking for a specific input until he types it right or timeout kicks him out.

```
void handler (int signum) 
{
inputErr==1;// global parameter
}
```

Is there any work around for me to skip that line of reading the input after returning from the handler? 
Or at least managing to print a proper message to the user that timeout occured?and not just return and get stuck on the input again lol.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Yes. You can use a combination of `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`.

Comment: Why not print and exit from the handler function itself ? You could do that _if_ you exit from the program.

Comment: Well, you can have the `read` call be interrupted via `siginterrupt(SIGALRM, 1)` and test for the cancellation flag in the `EINTR` error branch. Then again `longjmp` should also be signal safe. Things get tricky if `ReadLineMethod` isn't under your own control though, in which case you might needed some painful hack such as closing the standard input file descriptor.

Comment: What does this third-party code do if you omit `SA_RESTART` from your signal flags in your `sigaction` structure?  It's possible that might cause the `read()` call to fail with `EINTR` and then `ReadLineMethod()` will return an error.

Comment: Thanks for comments guys.

@user1952500 it's not a straight away exit from program..

Comment: @DYZ can you be more specific in my case how to implement it?

Comment: @doynax yeah the ReadLineMethod  is not really under my control,it's the biggest problem.
how can i use longjmp correctly here?

Comment: @AndrewHenle SA_RESTART is not set by default ,and i tried to check for errno ==EINTR  but didn't help.

Comment: @rozmanro: You _can_ `siglongjmp` out of a signal handler to abort. The problem is that unless `ReadLineMethod` is in on it then the termination may easily place the system in an inconsistent state, as might a terminated thread or `fork`. _Especially_ is clean-up is required and background threads are used. Instead I would suggest trying `close(STDIN_FILENO)` to forcibly terminate the read. Alternatively, if _all_ you require is to display a time-out message before uncleanly terminating the process, then directly `write` the abort message and `_exit` from signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag that the handler raises. Condition the printing with this flag. You will need to protect this flag with a mutex.

Comment: Where to put the conditioning?
Because handler returns to If(ReadLineMethod()>0) line which i'm stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't allowed to reimplement `ReadLineMethod()` to be more reasonable, how about using threads? I'm not an expert on pthread, but you could probably set things up so that `ReadLineMethod` happens on one thread and polling for the error happens on another thread. There even seems to be a pthread_cancel function that can forcibly stop the reader thread if need be: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html

Comment: I'm already with many threads here,would better avoid using more threads for this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have so many restrictions, one way to get total control over this system will be:

1. Create a thread and run `ReadLineMethod()` in that thread.
2. Create another thread and use a timer in that thread. Do not use signals but detect otherwise that the rime has run out.
3. When the timer thread understands that the timer has run our, let it kill the thread in (1).
4. Else, if `ReadLineMethod()` has run to completion cleanly, let the timer thread do nothing and complete.

Of course, this is convoluted because of the requirements. If the fundamental requirement is known, there may be better alternatives.